# Get only 1 row from 3rd table with inner join

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I'm fetching 3 tables:

questions, answers and members.

This is working just fine, but the thing is, that I would like to only get the first row of `answers` of each question. So if a question has 50 answers, I would like to only show a snippet of one of them. I have looked at subqueries and left joins, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

```
$queryGQ = "SELECT 
    questions.q_id,
    questions.question,
    questions.description,
    questions.link,
    questions.m_id AS qMID,
    questions.timestamp,
    questions.linktitle,
    questions.answers,
    questions.upvotes,
    answers.a_id,
    answers.q_id AS qQID,
    answers.answer,
    members.m_id AS mMID,
    members.navn,
    members.avidaname
        FROM
    questions
        INNER JOIN
    answers ON answers.q_id = questions.q_id
        INNER JOIN
    members ON questions.m_id = members.m_id
        WHERE public = '1'
        ORDER BY questions.timestamp DESC LIMIT $TheLimit";

    if ($stmtGQ = $con->prepare($queryGQ)) {

        /* execute statement */
        $stmtGQ->execute();

        /* bind result variables */
        $stmtGQ->bind_result($q_id, $question, $description, $link, $qMID, $timestamp, $linktitle, $answers, $upvotes, $aAID, $qQID, $answer, $mMID, $navn, $avidaname);

        /* fetch values */
        while ($stmtGQ->fetch()) {
            //MAGIC HAPPENS
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` ... _what_ isn't working?  Your query seems to be along the lines of what you describe that you want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm getting ALL the rows of the answers. I only need one (1) of the rows to return. Some questions got 50 answers and I would like to show just a snippet of one of them. I hope I'm explaining it right :)

Comment: Is there any logic for which answer gets displayed?  Or, do you want a random selection each time?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - If I could, I would show the answer with the most upvotes. Something like this: SELECT a_id, answer FROM answers ORDER BY upvotes DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to retain the answer with the most upvotes, then you may add another join to a subquery which finds that most popular answer for each question.  Then, use it to filter your result set to just one answer per question.

```
SELECT 
    q.q_id,
    q.question,
    q.description,
    q.link,
    q.m_id AS qMID,
    q.timestamp,
    q.linktitle,
    q.answers,
    q.upvotes,
    a.a_id,
    a.q_id AS qQID,
    a.answer,
    m.m_id AS mMID,
    m.navn,
    m.avidaname
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN answers a
    ON a.q_id = q.q_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT q_id, MAX(upvotes) AS max_upvotes
    FROM answers
    GROUP BY q_id
) a2
    ON a.q_id = a2.q_id AND a.upvotes = a2.max_upvotes
INNER JOIN members m
    ON q.m_id = m.m_id
WHERE
    public = '1'
ORDER BY
    q.timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Yes. YES! Thank you very much, I battled a lot with this. Now I will spend the next 10 minutes trying to understand what you did. FANTASTIC!

Comment: Tim, I know this post is a bit old, but I have realized that while this code works great, it doesn't show questions WITHOUT an answer. It somehow possible to modify this code so it also displays questions without answers? Thank you.

Comment: @NielsHermann Changing all the inner joins to left joins should do the trick `:-)`

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you. You really need to make a website or something - I would def. hire you for some freelance jobs.

Comment: By the way, if `public` is not a column in the `questions` table it might also have to move to the `ON` clause of one of the joins.  But, that the above comment seems to work already, maybe you can ignore this.

Comment: It works 50% - At first sight it looked like it worked with no problems, but after changing all inner joins to left joins it ignores the fact that it should fetch the answer with the highest amount of upvotes. But it does indeed shows questions with and without answers.